# How to automatically POLL a rest API/Service

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am going to be building an application that utilises the woo commerce api to pull in orders and order information from wordpress and woo commerce.

I have built a real basic app for testing which utilises the PHP library for the woo commerce rest api, this works fine however I have to manually refresh the page or stick a page reload command in the app to check for new data. I want this to happen automatically.

I believe essentially I need a server of some sort in between that polls the woo commerce api for changes and that can then push this to the client.

Do you have any suggestions as to what can be used to accomplish this?

My Idea is:

WooCommerce Rest API <-> MY new Server(to look for and process changes) <-> My Client (HTML, JavaScript)

Does something like this exist already or can I build a server/service that will talk to the woocommerce api?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can use setInterval or setTimeout to poll a service.

Here is one example: (requires jQuery)

```
(function pollService() {
  $.getJSON('/poll.php', function (response) {
    // ... Do something with the response
    setTimeout(pollService, 1000);
  });
}());
```

Comment: Awesome, so i would essentially do this all on the client side? and if it detects an update from the woocommerce api i would just update the data on the client?

Comment: Exactly. You've got it.